# How install Phpmyadmin on linux lite (ubuntu based)?

Tags: ubuntu, software-installation, php, phpmyadmin

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install phpmyadmin
```

Didn't work -- it doesn't find the package.

What repository do I need? I added: `ppa:ondrej/php`

I searched on "synaptic package manager" too, and nothing!

Answer (score 0):

1. `apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y`
2. Next make sure you have the PHP module mcrypt installed with apt-get install mcrypt
3. Restart apache with `/etc/init.d/apache2 restart`
4. Next install phpmyadmin: `apt-get install phpmyadmin`